# Segmentation fault while taking array input in NASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

This is NASM code to calculate even and odd numbers in a given array of size n. But while taking array input, I am getting "Segmentation Fault". After spending 2 hours on debugging, I found that `mov eax,dword[ebx+4*ecx]` and `mov dword[ebx+ 4*eax],ecx` were giving segmentation fault. But I can't find a way to remove it.

Please help

```
newline: db '',10
msg1: db "Enter n : "
l1: equ $-msg1
msg2: db "Enter a number : "
l2: equ $-msg2
msg3:db "Odd numbers : "
l3: equ $-msg3
msg4:db "Even numbers : "
l4: equ $-msg4

section .bss
array :resd 100
n: resd 1
num:resd 1
temp: resd 1
counter: resd 1
even: resd 1
odd: resd 1

section .text
global _start:

_start:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg1
    mov edx, l1
    int 80h

    call read_num
    mov eax,dword[num]
    mov dword[n],eax
    call print_num

    mov eax,0
    mov ebx,[array]
    call read_array

    mov ecx,0
    forloop:
        cmp ecx,dword[n]
        jne print_ans
        mov eax,dword[ebx+4*ecx]
        and eax,2
        add edx,eax
        jmp forloop

    print_ans:
        mov dword[even],edx
        mov eax,dword[num]
        sub eax,edx
        mov dword[odd],eax

        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,msg3
        mov edx,l3
        int 80h

        mov eax,dword[odd]
        mov dword[odd],eax
        call print_num

        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,msg4
        mov edx,l4
        int 80h

        mov eax,dword[even]
        mov dword[even],eax
        call print_num

    exit:
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h

;Function to read an array of numbers
read_array:
    pusha
    array_loop:
        cmp eax,dword[n]
        je end_read
        
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,msg2
        mov edx,l2
        int 80h

        call read_num
        mov ecx,dword[num]
        mov dword[ebx+ 4*eax],ecx
        inc eax
        jmp array_loop

; Function to read a multidigit number
read_num:
    pusha
    mov dword[num],0
    reading:
        mov eax,3
        mov ebx,0
        mov ecx,temp
        mov edx,1
        int 80h

        cmp dword[temp],10
        je end_read
        sub dword[temp],30h
        mov eax, dword[num]
        mov ebx,10
        mov edx,0
        mul ebx
        add eax,dword[temp]
        mov dword[num],eax
        jmp reading

end_read:
    popa
    ret

; Function to print a multidigit number
print_num:
    pusha
    mov dword[counter],0
    
    cmp dword[num],0
    jne extract_num
    inc dword[counter]
    mov edx,0
    push edx
    jmp printing

    extract_num:
        cmp dword[num],0
        je printing
        inc dword[counter]
        mov edx,0
        mov eax,dword[num]
        mov ebx,10
        div ebx
        push edx
        mov dword[num],eax
        jmp extract_num

printing:
    cmp dword[counter],0
    je end_print
    pop edx
    add edx,30h
    mov dword[temp],edx
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,temp
    mov edx,1
    int 80h
    dec dword[counter]
    jmp printing

end_print:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,newline
    mov edx,1
    int 80h
    popa
    ret
```

Comment: With assembly language question, please always use the tag [tag:assembly] as well as the tag for the architecture in question (here [tag:x86]).

Comment: `mov ebx,[array]` loads `ebx` with the *value* from the first element of the array.  It seems like what you want instead is the *address* of the array, so make it `mov ebx, array`.

Comment: Finding the line that segfaults is not the end of the debugging process, just the beginning.  Segfault is an access to an invalid address, so if `mov eax,dword[ebx+4*ecx]` crashes then either `ebx` or `ecx` contains an incorrect value.  Work backwards in the code to figure out where those values came from and whether they are correct.

Comment: A debugger will tell you right away which instruction segfaults.  Next time, use a debugger which can show register values and lets you single step, and save yourself a couple hours of blindly messing around in the dark.

Comment: Thanks, @NateEldredge for pointing out the mistake and also if figured that my registers were being changed while printing inside the loop